# Open a .db file containing avro files using SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, avro

I have a .db file which contains the avro files as below

/home/mydir/mydb.db/example1

/home/mydir/mydb.db/example1.avsc

/home/mydir/mydb.db/example1/sample_avro_file.avro

I want to see the data in the avro file. So I am using sqlite to open the .db file as below

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mydir/mydb.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from example1", con)
```

But I get the below error

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * from example1': no such table: example1
```

What wrong am I doing here?
I am new to SQLITE and want inputs on how to read the avro file.

Comment: You should use something that can read an avro database, like the [avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html) package, not SQLite.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am aware that I can open the files using avro package. But I dont have that available on my system, so looking for alternatives. I know SQLITE can open .db files, so trying to use that. So, are you saying SQLITE cannot open a .db containing avro files and the only option is to have the package installed?

Comment: Correct.  SQLite opens SQLite files, not Avro files.